# Only Vga works (not dvi) - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nvidia, ati, vga, dvi

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10. For some reason I can not get the DVI to work. The monitor says: Cable not connected. 
The VGA cable works, but the everything looks blurry. 
The resolution is fine 1920 x 1200 and it even knows that I have BenQ 24".

I have 2 video cards.

- AH3450/HTP/256M (ATI Radeon HD 3450) AGP (ports: VGA:ok DVI:not working).
- EN7600GT/2DHT/256M (nVidia®’s GeForce 7600GT) PCI-Express  (ports: DVI:not working DVI:not working)

What should I do to get my DVI:s to work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! DVI should just work. You're using two different graphics card on which this both happens. Are you sure you're not looking at a hardware issue? Damaged cable, damaged monitor connector, etc.

Comment: Sadly I erased my windows, to test the DVI in it. Before it worked fine with the ATI Radeon HD 3450. Now at least the monitor recognices, when I take off and on the cable DVI.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. DVI/HDMI worked in 12.04, but I haven't been able to get it to work in 12.10.  I will be upgrading to 13.04 to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's your cards?
I have a Samsung Syncmaster SA300 and it takes both types of input and had the same problem when I connected the DVI cable to it.
I found out that I have to switch between inputs for it to work. There must be somewhere on the monitor that lets you switch between inputs?
Mine was near the on/off selection.
You never know, it might be something simple like that...

Comment: Yes, my momitpr has a bottom like that, to switch cable types. But it does not help. DVI just says: Not connected and using VGA cable, everything looks too blurry.

Answer (score 0):

i got it fixed!!! I just change Ubuntu to 12.4.1 and in the begining it helped me to install good drivers. 
There is no way, I will go to 12.10 before its bugies get fixed!

BR. Johannes